# json - Grabbing key values and adding it to a loop

Tags: jquery, json, dust.js

Sorry bad title. I'm absolutely stumped on how to do this. I'm using dust for my templating (which works fine) but dust doesn't accept colons (:) as key names. So I'm trying to somehow still grab a key with a colon (user:description) and insert it into when I'm looping through my dust template. However the code below puts all the values into each individual div (see below). How would I make this work so that it enters the "user:description" value once per loop (or div creation)? I've been banging my head for hours. Any help is appreciated

```
var compiled = dust.compile($('.media-gallery').html(), "blocks");
var items = [];
dust.loadSource(compiled);

        $.getJSON("services/mediaType.json", function(data) {
            $.each( data.results, function( key, val ) {
                items.push("<div class='" + key + "'>" + val['user:description'] + "</div>");     
                dust.render("blocks", val, function(err, out) {
                    $('.media-filter').append(out);
                });                                        
            });
        $(".resource-description").append(items.join(""));
        });
```

**HTML with Dust**

```
<div class="media-gallery">        
    <h6>{pageTitle}</h6>
    <p class="content-type">{mediaType}</p>      
    <p class="resource-description"></p>
</div>
```

**TYPICAL OUTPUT**

```
<div class="media-gallery">        
    <h6>Dog Images</h6>
    <p class="content-type">image</p>      
    <p class="resource-description">
        <div class="0">cats description</div>
        <div class="1">mouse description</div>
        <div class="2">dog description</div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck unless you either write a custom helper or change the model to not contain :'s. There is an open issue on this problem. https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/229

Comment: Bummer thanks for the reply @rragan. Can you do this with a dust helper though? I've looked through the documentation and haven't found something that does this unless I'm just overlooking something.